# How to detect if column contains value doesn't fitting it's width?

Tags: excel, ms-office, add-in

I need to detect if column has some values which need more width (that ones shown as ###### in the grid)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find Text Cells That Are Too Small to Display Contents](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2105361/find-text-cells-that-are-too-small-to-display-contents)

Answer (score 1):

The solution depends on how the data is entered into the cells.. the below might get you started:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    Cells.Columns.AutoFit
End Sub
```

Or to affect one sheet - e.g. in a macro - you could change it to pass through the sheet number/name

```
Sub SetColWidth()
    Sheets(1).Columns.AutoFit
End Sub
```

or to go through ALL the sheets and set them all at once:

```
Sub SetColWidthAllSheets()
    Dim s As Worksheet
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each s In Sheets
        s.Columns.AutoFit
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End Sub
```

Hope this helps

EDIT: Added ScreenUpdating to above code.

Comment: Calling AutoFit is not acceptable, it makes worksheet blinking even when no widths are updated actually (and my data are updated frequently, so this will happen again and again)

Comment: You could try turning off the screen updating before and after the autofit:  Application.ScreenUpdating = False/true

Comment: It's not acceptable anyway, because I need auto-fit for a limited range only (not the whole column)